# TeamCity 10, how to get project id

Tags: teamcity

I have just upgraded our TeamCity server from old 7 version to 10. In our deployment to the test environment we are deploying through FTP, before we used the **%system.teamcity.projectName%** to put together the path to where the artifact are stored. Apparently this has changed so now the **%system.teamcity.projectName%** reflects the name directly along with white space, which isn't part of the directory d:\TeamCity.BuildServer\system\artifacts\FooDeployment\ that exist.

Looking at the genera settings page, there is a "Project ID" which is similar to the directory needed, but I can't find any parameter reflecting this ?

Is there a simple way to get the Project Id as a %system% parameter, or maybe just get the final artifact directory ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though looking for this previously and couldn't find it, I just found out that there is a parameter pointing to the ID %teamcity.project.id% giving me the Project ID string as needed.